# Create an offset list python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I want python to generate a list `[['A', 'B', 'C']]` and then append another list so it's `[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['B', 'C', 'A']]` and continue until it is finished. I've been working with python for a while now but can't seem to find a way to do this.
Any help would be nice.

I've tried a `for` loop of:

```
x = list("ABCDEFGHIJ...")
for i in range(0,55):
    for j in range(0,55):
        y = (j+55) - (i+55)
        list[i][j] = x[y]
```

so yeah, thanks for any help.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish. Are you trying to get all the permutations of `list('abc')`? If so, `itertools.permutations` is your friend.

Comment: I think he's treating the original list as a ring.

Comment: @2rs2ts ah-ha! You may be right :) If so, g.d.d.c's answer is perfect.

Comment: You should always tell what is exactly your problem. As is, your code cannot run, as you are assigning a value to an index of "list", which is a type. Another hint: you'll have to build your empty grid first, as you cannot assign to an index out of range. And your fourth line could be simplified...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just trying to append a rotated list, here is how to that:

```
>>> x=[]
>>> x.append(list('ABC'))
>>> x
[['A', 'B', 'C']]
>>> x.append(x[-1][1:]+x[-1][:1])
>>> x
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['B', 'C', 'A']]
```

Which you can continue:

```
>>> x.append(x[-1][1:]+x[-1][:1])
>>> x
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['B', 'C', 'A'], ['C', 'A', 'B']]
```

And when you say 'continue until done' you may mean something like this?:

```
x=[list('ABCD')]

def rotate(l,n):
    return l[n:] + l[:n]

while True:
    rl=rotate(x[-1], 1)
    if len(x)>1 and x[0]==rl:
        break
    else:    
        x.append(rl)

print x    
# [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['B', 'C', 'D', 'A'], ['C', 'D', 'A', 'B'], ['D', 'A', 'B', 'C']]
```

Answer (score 5):

You might be looking for the functionality in a `deque`

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> d = deque('ABC')
>>> d
deque(['A', 'B', 'C'])
>>> d.rotate(-1)
>>> d
deque(['B', 'C', 'A'])
```

Comment: Piggybacking on this answer: to get the desired result (a list of rotations of "ABC"), you could do this: `x = "ABC"; L = [x]; d = deque(x); for y in range(len(x)-1): d.rotate(-1); L.append(list(d))`